# Create table with variable labels in R

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am looking for an R package that can create publication-quality tables in an `rmarkdown` word format report such that the tables contain variable labels. I would like a one-way table with the label "Flower species" like the one generated from Stata:

```
tab Species

     Flower |
    species |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
     setosa |         50       33.33       33.33
 versicolor |         50       33.33       66.67
  virginica |         50       33.33      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |        150      100.00
```

I have my variable labels set via the help of `label {Hmisc}` function:

```
library(Hmisc)
label(iris$Species) <- 'Flower species'
label(iris$Species)
[1] "Flower species"
```

Now I would like to tabulate species with the label 'Flower species' and here are my options:

Option 1:

```
library(catspec)
ctab(iris$Species)
            Count Total %
Var1                     
setosa      50.00   33.33
versicolor  50.00   33.33
virginica   50.00   33.33
```

Problem is that the label displayed is 'Var1' instead of 'Flower species'

Option 2:

```
library(sjPlot) 
sjt.frq(iris$Species)
```

[image]

This displays the variable label as required but this function only generates a HTML output table and cannot be exported into `rmarkdown` word format output while retaining the clean table format.

Option 3:

From [this](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/6975_c4943349b6174f448104a5513fed59a9.html) page:

```
source("http://pcwww.liv.ac.uk/~william/R/crosstab.r")
crosstab(iris, row.vars='Species')

Species       Count Total %
  setosa      50.00   33.33
  versicolor  50.00   33.33
  virginica   50.00   33.33
  Sum        150.00  100.00
```

This function does not display the label 'Flower species' and I am not sure if there are options to specify how to display labels.

Comment: Do you mean to add dynamic caption to a table? Maybe see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867689) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33965560)?

Comment: No, the caption might be good to have but I am more concerned with the variable label

Comment: Does `knitr::kable(ctab(iris$Species)$ctab, caption = 'Flower Species')` suit you?

Comment: This approach produces a table with the required label. However, I would like the label defined by `label(iris$Species) <- 'Flower species'` picked automatically without having to specify `caption = 'Flower Species'`. Moreover, the following does not work: `knitr::kable(ctab(iris$Species)$ctab, caption = label(iris$Species))`

Comment: Well I can't get you any further. But `knitr::kable(ctab(iris$Species)$ctab, caption = label(iris$Species))` does work for me.

Comment: @martin. I get the table in the rmarkdown word output using `knitr::kable(ctab(iris$Species)$ctab, caption = label(iris$Species))` but it has no caption.

Comment: Neither do I see the label in the HTML output if I run that command solely in the console. But the docx output does show the label, if it is set correctly.

Comment: @martin I had left out the `label(iris$Species) <- 'Flower species'` in  my rmarkdown. It works now

Comment: You can import a HTML-file in word-processors, so simply generate a HTML-document with knitr, and open the HTML-file in Word/Writer/... See also [the pkg-vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjPlot/vignettes/sjtbasic.html).

Comment: @martin Though the `knitr::kable` approach works, it does not respond to `ctab` options like decimal places specification. `knitr::kable(ctab(iris$Species, dec.places=1)$ctab, caption = label(iris$Species))` This still gives the default 5 decimal places

Comment: `knitr::kable(ctab(iris$Species)$ctab, caption = label(iris$Species), digits = 1)`

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer It works, thanks. `knitr::kable(ctab(iris$Species)$ctab, caption = label(iris$Species), digits = 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the arsenal package. Try this:

```
library(arsenal)
library(rmarkdown)

t1<-tableby(~Species,data = iris)
labels(t1)<- c(Species='Flower species')

write2word(t1,"d:/test.doc")
```

This produces the following table. See the arsenal docmentation for further help, they have very good vignettes

[image]

Comment: This function gives pretty output that renders nicely in rmarkdown

Comment: Thank you!  This was just what I needed.